# Unity3D gives hundrends of errors when building the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, publish

so my Unity worked fine until now, last time I built the game was yesterday and everything worked fine. Since yesterday the only thing that I did is that I changed some colliders and removed facebook gamecenter plugin. Now, when I try to play the game, everything is fine, but when I try to build it, it starts giving me 250 errors in total.

The last error always says :

> "Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors"

Others error are connected to the standard assets.

Screenshots:
[image: screenshot01]
[image: screenshot02]

Comment: "Could not find *MonoBehaviour!?*" Uninstall and reinstall Unity.

Comment: If I do that, would I lose all my files (library,assets etc)

Comment: Uninstalling doesn't delete your project files.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that, will let you know, thanks :)

Comment: Yep, it worked, thank you very much. What a relief that I made several back-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this happens. There a few options of fixing it, but the easiest one to simply re-install Unity.

PS: You wont lose any data.